Can connect from desktop to laptop; But, cannot do the opposite
I have a Win11 desktop PC and a Win10 laptop.
Both are running Remotely. Both are connected to the WiFi.
I can connect from the desktop to the laptop.
However, I cannot connect from the laptop to the desktop.
What could be the issue?

While you imply things, you don't actually explicitly state what sort of connection you're attempting between these devices. Do you mean you are connecting using Remotly? What message(s) do you get? Have you checked their guides? What is your network configuration?

@music2myear, I am trying to connect to the remote pc using Remotely so that I can work on the remote PC from my laptop.

@music2myear, There is no message. The laptop's Remotely tries to connect by attempting several times, and then gives up.

@music2myear, I am using WiFi. What do u mean by network config?
